# Internet speed testing software for Lubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, lubuntu, internet

I want a Internet speed testing software for Lubuntu which is fully GUI.

Comment: www.speedtest.net ?

Comment: You can just use websites like http://smart-ip.net/speed-test ...

Comment: i asked for a doftware not a website @Dave

Comment: Just use the website like any normal person stop overcomplicating your life.  There's even a terminal version of speedtest.net which you can use but nobody is dumb enough to write a dedicated gtk application since you can just point your favourite web browser at a web page

Comment: @Dave no, when i speedtest with forefox, speed is 3.22mbps and chromium, 4mbps thats why i aske dit

Comment: no i only need GUI

Answer (score 3):

**1) Install *speedtest-cli*(1)** e.g. using the following terminal commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install speedtest-cli
```

**2)** Copy & paste the following simple bash script into a new plain text file (e.g. ~/.bin/SpeedTestGUI.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
notify-send "Retrieving speedtest.net configuration..." -i gtk-dialog-info -t 1 -u normal && notify-send "Retrieving speedtest.net server list..." -i gtk-dialog-info -t 1 -u normal && notify-send "Selecting best server based on ping..." -i gtk-dialog-info -t 1 -u normal && notify-send "Your download and upload speeds will be calculated and displayed in a popup window shortly..." -i gtk-dialog-info -t 5 -u normal &
TMPFILE=`mktemp -t speedtest.XXXXXX`
speedtest-cli 2>&1 > $TMPFILE
# Check if the temp file is empty: if true there's something wrong with network
if [ ! -s "$TMPFILE" ]; then
 zenity --error --text="Network Error!"
else
# Determine ISP source server, best target server, dowload and upload speeds
SOURCE="$(cat "$TMPFILE"|sed -n '3,3p'|sed -e 's/Testing from //g' -e 's/\.\.\.//g')"
TARGET="$(cat "$TMPFILE"|sed -n '5,5p'|sed -e 's/Hosted by //g' -e 's/: .\+$//g')"
DOWNLD="$(cat "$TMPFILE"|sed -n '7,7p'|sed -e 's/Download: //g')"
UPLOAD="$(cat "$TMPFILE"|sed -n '9,9p'|sed -e 's/Upload: //g')"
# Display information obtained
zenity --info --text="\nISP Server: <b>$SOURCE</b>\n\nTarget Server: <b>$TARGET</b>\n\nDownload Speed: <b>$DOWNLD</b>\n\nUpload Speed: <b>$UPLOAD</b>"
# Remove the temp file when the user closes the zenity window
rm -f $TMPFILE
fi
```

**3) Make it executable and run it** - either by clicking in your file manager or by adding it to a menu.

A Zenity info box will display basic internet speed details.

(1) Further info: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/how-to-test-internet-speed-via-command.html

Comment: I think zenity is installed by default on most Ubuntu flavors.

Comment: @DKBose : Thanks for reminding; I removed zenity installation from the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try "System Load Indicator". It's a panel app that will display the network usage and speed,along with stuff like memory, CPU and hard-disk in your panel.

To install it via command line

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload
```

Once you have done that,just type the following in your command line to start it.

```
indicator-multiload
```

The applet will automatically start the next time you boot. Hope it helps.